# How to check that one property more than another in jschema?

Tags: json, swagger, swagger-ui, jsonschema

```
    'MyObj': {
                    'type': 'object',
                    'properties': {
                        'width': {
                            'type': 'integer',
                            'minimum': 1
                        },
                        'height': {
                            'type': 'integer',
                            'minimum': 1
                        },
                        'sheetWidth': {
                            'type': 'integer',
                            'minimum': 1,
                        },
                        'sheetHeight': {
                            'type': 'integer',
                            'minimum': 1,
                        }
                    },
                    'required': [
                        'width',
                        'height'
                    ]
                }
```

Is it possible to check than 'height' more than 'sheetWidth'?

Seems like I have to use custom validation, but I'm not sure, and it would be great to check it with json-schema.

I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged this question `swagger` - Swagger/OpenAPI Specification uses a [subset of JSON Schema Draft 4](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#schemaObject), which does not support that kind of validation.

You can only document this verbally in the property description:

```
'height': {
    'type': 'integer',
    'minimum': 1
    'description': 'Must be more than sheetWidth.'
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a proposed [$data reference](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv#data-reference) that is supported in [Ajv](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv)

```
{
  "properties": {
    "height": {
      "type": "integer",
      "minimum": { "$data": "1/sheetWidth" }
    },
    "sheetWidth": {
      "type": "integer",
      "minimum": 1,
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but I use json-schema